How to make a captive redirection portal for a SSID?
I have a PHP project running on one of my computers connected to my home network, I access the project from the same computer by localhost/myserver and by my other devices connected to the same network by typing the local IP of the computer where the project is hosted, 192.168.0.42/myserver, i.e the IP of the local machine then it goes to the website homepage, but this has to be done manually by typing the IP+name in the browser of all devices
How can I make a captive portal that shows up in the list of available networks, and then on connecting to it, it redirects to the 192.168.0.41/myserver page on the browser of that device?

For an SSID? Captive portals are function of the wireless network, and must be supported by the wireless router (or device acting AS the wireless router). So the answer is yes, you can do that. You just need to look through your router's configs, or find a router that supports captive portals. What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried?

@music2myear Hello, first of all thank you for responding, I have tried to look at tools like Connectify, MyPublicWi-Fi which transmit Hotspot signals, basically my PC which will be running it is gonna have captive portal and then redirection to IPofthatlocalmachine/myserver/login.php So it will be for kind of filesharing/redirection means, not for sharing Internet. Will have to add hosts and tweak a few settings of Wi-Fi, I heard it is possible.
